# Selecting data from MySQL based on the results of a previous query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables:
*session* which contains columns *username, lastSeen, currentlyOnline*
and
*users* which contains columns *username, userLocation, userAge*

I need to select information (*userLocation, userAge*) of the currently online users (where *currentlyOnline* equals 1). I was thinking of selecting the usernames from the *session* table and then selecting the information in a loop with another query, but maybe there is a simpler solution?

Your input is appreciated :)

Comment: How two tables are mapped ?

Comment: @swapnesh Huh? I'm sorry, I am a total noob in MySQL. What do you mean? They both share the same column username and that is about it :)

Comment: thats ok then look at prodigitalson solution then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT u.userLocation, u.userAge, u.username
FROM users u, session s
WHERE u.username = s.username
AND s.currentlyOnline = ?
```

The `?` is whatever value means they are online. I also added the username to the select because you'll probably want this and it's silly to run another query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN. 
Example: 
    SELECT userLocation, userAge FROM users INNER JOIN session ON users.username = session.username WHERE session.currentlyOnline = 1

Answer (score 0):

a join will do that perfectly :

```
SELECT users.userLocation, users.userAge, users.username
FROM users
JOIN session ON users.username = session.username
WHERE session.currentlyOnline = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join here. From here it can be perceived username is the forignkey for session table with users tables. In that case use this query.

```
select  userLocation, userAge from users as u JOIN session as s ON u.username = s.username AND s.currentlyOnline = 1
```

It is always better to use a foriegnkey as a integer and primary key of one table. Here if you keep id as primarykey in users table and user_id as forignkey in session table and join using that it would be great.